# MVC: post, catching form values into property of page model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Alright...this may be a bit backwards but, I only need to do it in one spot.

I have a Model

```
public class LoginModel : xxx.Models.PageVars
{

public Item.LoginAttempt LoginAttempt { get; set; }

public LoginModel()
{
    // does a bunch of stuff here...mainly to set the layout properties from PageVar

    this.LoginAttempt = new Item.LoginAttempt();
}
}
```

Login Attempt is a simple obj (for now)

```
    //  login attempt
public class LoginAttempt
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

My controller

```
    public ActionResult Login()
    {

        return View("Login", new Models.LoginModel());
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoginAttempt(LoginAttempt model)
    {
        return View("Login", model);
    }
```

In my view 
    @model  xxx.Models.LoginModel

Is there a way to use the property of the obj/model from LoginModel for the @model.

I can get the values from FormCollection or request but...that's not optimal.

thoughts???

tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model for your GET should match the model for your POST. Otherwise, you're not playing on the same field. In order to allow the binding of data from a POST to a model, the HTML Helpers will generate a name that matches the access path of the property in the view's model. In other words, in your form, based on the model being `LoginModel`, your field names will be `LoginAttempt.Email` and `LoginAttempt.Password`. But, in the POST action, you're accepting just `LoginAttempt`, so the modelbinder is expecting to see data for `Email` and `Password`, which it won't find.

There's actually not even any need for this nested class. Just put your `Email` and `Password` fields directly on `LoginModel` and use that for both your view and your POST parameter. Then, you won't have any issues because everything will match up.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you have the form post controller action accept the parent model LoginModel instead of LoginAttempt? That way, the default MVC model binding should automatically parse the submitted values into the LoginModel and you'll have acces to LoginAttempt.

If it isn't then your form needs to use the prefix values in the names of the properties on the form. This is done automatically when you use TextboxFor, DropdownListFor etc.

In your example, the names of the form fields should start with LoginAttempt.Email etc

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it work 2 ways.  First way would be to rename your `LoginAttempt model` parameter to be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoginAttempt(LoginAttempt loginModel)
{
    return View("Login", model);
}
```

But i would use the `Bind(Prefix)` option

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoginAttempt([Bind(Prefix="LoginModel")] LoginAttempt model)
{
    return View("Login", model);
}
```

you can't really return model of type LoginAttempt to the view though so you'd have to do even more work to get it to work if you're set on doing it this way.  You should probably be redirecting to a different page instead of returning the `Login` view if it succeeds.  Other wise return `new LoginModel() {LoginAttempt = model}`